# Animations don't work when I drag them to Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the first time I try to use animations in Unity so my friend built a campfire in blender and also made animations so the fire seems like it's moving. When he converted it to fbx and sent it to me, I downloaded the fbx, dragged it to the Unity project. I thought that the animations should work and I should see the fire moving when I play the game, but unfortunately the fire seemed like it's a not moving object. [I screen recorded it so you will understand the problem better](https://youtu.be/OyOwjJCq1IM). If anyone knows how to fix this problem, it will really help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all You have to check FBX import settings to be sure, that animation is exist. Select your fbx in Unity and switch to 'Animation' Tab in Inspector. If Animation is exist, You'll see animation import settings. Be sure toggle 'Import Animation is active':

[image]

If Your FBX does not have animation, in animation tab You'll see message 'No animation data available in this model'.

If FBX is okay, the next step is checking your fire gameobject. It must contains Animator component with some animation controller. This animation controller will play anim clip from your FBX.

But first af all I recommend your check this: [Unity Animation Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2018.4/Manual/class-Animation.html)

Comment: I don't know if my animation actually exists, it's pretty weird. I will add an answer with a screen shot. Maybe you could tell me if my animation exists